# hierarchical clustering using flann in opencv

Tags: opencv, hierarchical-clustering

I'm trying to use a method hierarchicalClustering from opencv 2.4.2.

It work without error, but the problem is, that I don't undertstand the parametrs it accepts eg. branching...

And i think it couses my problem that i get always just one cluster.

My input is a cv::Mat of LBPH features (for face detection) number of rows is 12 and number of cols is 6272. 
No matter what is the value of branching factor I get always just one cluster and its centroid is mean of rows from input matrix grouppeed_one_ferson_features. 
Could you advice ???

THANK a LOT!!!

heres the code:

```
cv::Mat groupped_one_person_features;  
.... // fill grouppeed_one_ferson_features with data 
int  Nclusters=50;
cv::Mat centroids (Nclusters,Features.data[0][0].cols,CV_32FC1);
int count = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<cvflann::L1<float>>groupped_one_person_features,centroids,cvflann::KMeansIndexParams(2000,11,cvflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP));
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you missed a parenthesis in your last line:

```
int count = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<cvflann::L1<float>>(groupped_one_person_features,centroids,cvflann::KMeansIndexParams(2000,11,cvflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP));
```

In the order, the parameters are (according to `flann_base.hpp`):

- The points to be clustered
- The computed cluster centers. Matrix should be preallocated and centers.rows is the number of clusters requested.
- The clustering parameters
- The distance to be used for clustering

Therefore, if you always get one cluster, it possibly means that your `centroids` matrix only has one row. Can you verify this?

The parameters of `KMeansIndexParams` are (according to `kmeans_index.h`):

- branching factor: the number of children of a node in the tree
- iterations: max iterations to perform in one kmeans clustering (kmeans tree)
- centers_init: algorithm used for picking the initial cluster centers for kmeans tree
- cb_index: cluster boundary index. Used when searching the kmeans tree

Comment: This meaning of the parameters can easily be read from the documentation. Do you maybe _actually_ know what these parameters mean, i.e. what kind of behavior will changing them cause?